# Error: process finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gluon

I am currently trying to build an android apk for my eclipse java project.

When using the "gradle-w android" command in command prompt, I keep running into this error

```
Execution failed for task ':PVZApp:processAndroidResourcesDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build- 
tools\28.0.3\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Below is a sample of my build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.16'

}
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
  jcenter()
  maven {
    url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
}
}

mainClassName = '---------' //Omitted from post

dependencies {
compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:5.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}

jfxmobile {
downConfig {
    version = '3.8.6'
    // Do not edit the line below. Use Gluon Mobile Settings in your project context menu instead
    plugins 'display', 'lifecycle', 'statusbar', 'storage'
}
android {
    manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
    compileSdkVersion = 28;
    buildToolsVersion = '28.0.3'


        dexOptions {
    incremental = true;
    preDexLibraries = false
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g" 
             }
    compileSdkVersion = 28;
    buildToolsVersion = '28.0.3'
}
ios {
    infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
    forceLinkClasses = [
            'com.gluonhq.**.*',
            'javax.annotations.**.*',
            'javax.inject.**.*',
            'javax.json.**.*',
            'org.glassfish.json.**.*'
    ]
}
}
```

Also below is a sample of my AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<manifest android:versionName="1.0" android:versionCode="1" 
package="com.gluonapplication" 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="true"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="21" android:minSdkVersion="4"/>


-<application android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" 
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="PVZApp">


-<activity android:name="javafxports.android.FXActivity" 
android:label="PVZApp" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">

<meta-data android:name="main.class" 
android:value="com.gluonapplication.GluonApplication"/>

<meta-data android:name="debug.port" android:value="0"/>


-<intent-filter>

<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>

</intent-filter>

</activity>

<activity android:name="com.gluonhq.impl.charm.down.plugins.android.PermissionRequestActivity"/>

</application>

</manifest>
```

A lot of the errors seem to be pointing to the AndroidManifest.xml file as the command prompt prints errors such as  "No resource identifier found for attribute 'name' in package" referring to AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: i suggest you to try to use Android Studio bcoz it made some features easily and can debug easily

Comment: Have you tried to run first any of the samples [here](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples)? You mentioned "lot of the errors", can you edit your post and add more detailed stack traces?